# “Time Series” descriptive statistics in data.table?

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

There's a transaction data with 4 fields: user_id, brand_id, type, time

```
bd = as.Date("2012-04-01")
SampleDT <- data.table(user_id = rep(c("A","B"), each = 5), brand_id = rep(1:5, c(4,1,3,1,1)), type = c(0,0,2,3,3,0,3,3,0,0), time = c(bd,bd+1,bd+1,bd+2,bd+2, bd+ -1:1, bd+2, bd+2))
```

Each observation records the user behavior on certain product at given time.

Within the field `Type`, there're 3 distinct values: 0, 2, 3

`0 : click`

`2: adding to shopping cart`

`3: buy`

First, I calculated what products are purchased by each user.

```
setkey(SampleDT, user_id, brand_id)
SampleDT[type ==3, .N, by = key(SampleDT)]
```

The following is as follows:

```
   user_id brand_id N
1:       A        1 1
2:       A        2 1
3:       B        3 2
```

Next,

I want to calculate for each `type = 3` given user_id, brand_id fixed, How many (type =0 or type = 2)? What is the statistics of clicking and adding to cart before purchasing, given user, product fixed?

There're 5 fields in the results. 
user_id, brand_id, N ( indicate the Nth time for one user buy certain product), Click.N (how many type = 0 before the purchase) , AddingtoCart.N ( how many type = 2 before the purchase)

Here's what I want:

```
    user_id brand_id N  Click.N AddingtoCart.N
1:     A      1      1    2        1
2:     A      2      1    0        0
3:     B      3      1    1        0
4:     B      3      2    0        0
```

```
setkey(SampleDT, user_id, brand_id, time)
SampleDT[, .I[type==3], by = key(SampleDT)]
```

I think first find the row locations, but I don't know how to proceed.

Could you please give some suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Update based on changes to user data and input in comments:

```
SampleDT[, purch.id := c(0, head(cumsum(type==3), -1)), by=list(user_id, brand_id)]
SampleDT[, 
  if(3 %in% type) .SD, 
  by=list(user_id, brand_id, purch.id)
][, 
  list(Click=sum(type==0), Cart=sum(type==2)), 
  by=list(user_id, brand_id, purch.id)
]
```

Produces:

```
   user_id brand_id purch.id Click Cart
1:       A        1        0     2    1
2:       A        2        0     0    0
3:       B        3        0     1    0
4:       B        3        1     0    0
```

Here we assume that all entries in the table are sequential, and that all actions for a particular user/brand can be attributed to the subsequent purchase.

The main change was adding a purchase id that increments every time there is a new purchase for a particular user/brand.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! sorry for the typo, I modified the code for SampleDT, and now it is correct. I tried your code, it failed when there're multiple purchases of certain goods given user fixed. You can check B bought brand_id = 3 twice. So there should be another column N which indicate the bought times.

Comment: @Bigchao, see update.  The results are the same, though my method produces a slightly different `N` column.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is excellent answer, especially in the j part, `if (3 %in% type) .SD`, I really learnt a lesson from this!